# Which package in Gentoo provides xmlcatalog command?

Tags: gentoo, portage

I got `xmlcatalog` not found error. I think I removed some system packages by mistake. Which package provides this tool? Is there a place online that I can check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is **libxml2**.

The best tool to search for package owning is `qfile`, but it require that you have already installed the package on the system.

```
$ type xmlcatalog

xmlcatalog is /usr/bin/xmlcatalog

$ qfile /usr/bin/xmlcatalog

dev-libs/libxml2 (/usr/bin/xmlcatalog)
```

You can also find info about the library where xmlcatalog is included in the [manual pages](http://www.xmlsoft.org/xmlcatalog_man.html).

Comment: If I already have `xmlcatalog` installed, or know where is the manual...I would not have posted this question.

Comment: @davidshen84 I gave you link to the manual, it is clearly stated there *libxml2*, what more do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Googled for a long time, and found http://www.portagefilelist.de/site/query.